Reverse categories order in hovermode on Plotly
I have a Plotly stacked barplot with specific categories order. On the plot, the categories stack from bottom to top as wanted : bronze, silver, gold.
However, it stacks on the reversed order on the hovermode : gold, silver and bronze (from bottom to top as well)
Is there any way to correct the order in the hovermode "x unified" ?
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

category_orders = {
    "medal": [
        "bronze",
        "silver",
        "gold",
    ]
}

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", category_orders=category_orders)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified", legend=dict(orientation="h"))
fig.show()


I don't think there is a way to do that : category_orders determines both the bar stacking and the unified hover stacking in that way because bars (with positive values) are stacked from bottom to top on the yaxis (unless you revert the yaxis range), but the hover tooltips always read from top to bottom, following that same order. The hover data are not really reversed, they just follow the trace indices order (dictated by category_orders: 0-bronze, 1-silver, 2-gold), and this is expected to work this way for most trace types.. except for stacked bars bar with barmode="relative".

So this is an edge case that looks like a bug, yet it can be addressed on the plotly.js side, you might want to open an issue with all the details. Note the issue could be a feature request asking for a way to specify the traces order in the unified hover tooltips, overriding the original trace indices order, eg. something like unified_hover_trace_order: [2, 1, 0] that users would set in the layout.
